# como resolver este trigger em MySQL?

Tags: mysql, trigger

```
create trigger tr_kmanterior before insert on t_consumos for each row
set new.kmanterior_c = (preview.kmatual_c);
```

OU

```
create trigger tr_kmanterior before insert on t_consumos for each row
set new.kmanterior_c = (old.kmatual_c);
```

Preciso colocar em `kmanterior_c`, o valor de `kmatual_c`, da linha anterior.

Já tentei com estes dois exemplos e outros, da erro ou cálculo errado.

Comment: Qual erro foi apresentado ?